# How to calculate Night Flight time during a flight?

Tags: time, astronomy, sun

I am currently working on a web app (Pilot Logbook) that requires a user to automatically calculate the period of flight spent in the night.
Currently, I have 
Departure Lat and Long and Departure Time in UTC 
Arrival Lat and Long and Arrival Time in UTC 
Sunset and Sunrise Times (Based on dates) for both Arrival and Departure airfields in UTC

An example:
Depart UK Edingburgh airport on the 23 April 2019 at 11:10 UTC
Arrive Riyadh Airport at 18:10 UTC
Total Time 7hr
day flight = ?
night flight = ?

I am wondering if there is a formula or method available that allows me to do this calculation (Which I can then convert to code)?

Would really appreciate some help

Thanks

Comment: Would [aviation.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Are you assuming no air currents?  For example, flying in the jet stream would greatly influence the answer.

Comment: That's correct,  I am assuming constant speed with the known total flight time. As pilots when we input our info we just want a quick estimation these times. ie, with the information available above, (Date, departure and arrival location and times) an estimation of night flight should be calculated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the time could get complex. As a first approximation: Subtract the time of sunrise at the eastern most airport from the time at the western airport. Divide this time difference into the distance between the two airports. The result is the average speed, v, of the sunrise along the flight path (assuming the path is a great circle).  Then you can write an equation for the position of the sunrise as a function if time.  x = (t - $t_o$) v where, x, is the distance from the eastern most port and, $t_o$, is the time of sunrise at that port.   A similar equation can give the position of the plane as measured from the same port. You can equate the two positions and solve for the time when the plane meets the sunrise. A similar calculation can be done for the sunset.  There are three problems with this: (1) The time of a sunrise at thirty thousand feet is not the same as when it is observed from the ground. (2) The speed of the sunrise along a great circle is not likely to be constant (and this may change with the seasons). (3) The flight path may not be along a great circle.
You may need to calculate (or model) the speed of the sunrise along each segment of the flight-path and use a simulation to find when it meets the plane.
Here's another option, use angular velocities: Assume that the sunrise moves to the west at a constant angular speed (360 degrees/day). Calculate the angular speed associated with the eastward component of the velocity of the plane for each short segment of the flight-path. Use a simulation to find when the sum of the angular displacements equals the difference in longitude of the two airports.